# I'm a place of iron, sand, and hell. Where am I?

Tags: riddle, geography

I'm a place.

> The land of a little child,
>
> With temperatures rather mild.
>
> A land of iron, sand, and hell,
>
> A second Queen stands guard as well.
>
> Key, little fly, Florida too
>
> Below a snake stand guard for you.

What place am I?

Hint:

> Arr, matey.

Further hint:

> ¿Cómo?

Comment: Should it rather be "Below a snake stand*s* guard for you."?

Comment: @Matsmath perhaps, but I was thinking of the "Key, little fly, and Florida" standing guard. Either way works.

Comment: Almost went with Saba... pero ¿cómo puede ser eso?

Comment: it has to be Australia. If there is a snake involved it's Australia. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are:

> [Culebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culebra,_Puerto_Rico), Puerto Rico?
>   "Snake Island", and also known as Isla Chiquita (“Little Island”) and Última Virgen (“Last Virgin”)

Comment: No, that's not it. You are in the right part of the world though.

Comment: Of course I am.

Answer (score 0):

> Martinique

Because

The land of a little child,

> One of the "lesser" Antilles?

With temperatures rather mild.

> Tropical climate

A land of iron, sand, and hell,

> A volcanic island

A second Queen stands guard as well.

> In between two "feminine" Islands - St Lucia and Dominica

Key, little fly, Florida too

Below a snake stand guard for you.

> Unofficial flag is a white snake on blue background

Comment: Nice username ;-)